# C# Deserialization Over TCP

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, stream

I have now an issue with deserializing an object sent over TCP.

When deserializing, I get the following SerializationException (code below):

> Additional information: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid
>   BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version
>   change between serialization and deserialization.

**Serialization code:**

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, ReplicableObject ro) {
            MemoryStream serializedObjectStream = new MemoryStream();
            Formatter.Serialize(serializedObjectStream, ro);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            bw.Write(serializedObjectStream.Length);
            serializedObjectStream.WriteTo(stream);
            serializedObjectStream.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }
```

**Deserialization code:**

```
public static List<ReplicableObject> ParseStreamForObjects(Stream stream) {
        List<ReplicableObject> result = new List<ReplicableObject>();
        while (true) {
            if (!(stream as NetworkStream).DataAvailable) break;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            int length = br.ReadInt32();
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes(length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            ms.Position = 0;
                            // ERROR OCCURS ON THE LINE BELOW
            result.Add((ReplicableObject) Formatter.Deserialize(ms));
            ms.Close();
            br.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The objects are being serialized at runtime, so I don't think it's a versioning issue. I am new to streaming etc, so I may have missed something obvious.

I'd like to suggest what I think it could be, but I'm really stuck. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`serializedObjectStream.Length` is a `long`.

You're writing a 64-bit value to the network, but you're trying to read it as a 32-bit `int`.